# Reordering dataset in stata

Tags: database, dataframe, stata

We have a dataset of 1222x20 in Stata.
There are 611 individuals, such that each individual is in 2 rows of the dataset. There is only one variable of interest in each second row of each individual that we would like to use.
This means that we want a dataset of 611x21 that we need for our analysis.

It might also help if we could discard each odd/even row, and merge it later.
However, my Stata skills let me down at this point and I hope someone can help us.

Maybe someone knows any command or menu option that we might give a try.
If someone knows such a code, the individuals are characterized by the variable `rescode`, and the variable of interest on the second row is called `enterprise`.

Below, the head of our dataset is given. There is a binary time variable `followup`, where we want to regress the `enterprise`(yes/no) as dependent variable at time `followup` = followup onto `enterprise` as independent variable at time `followup` = baseline

We have tried something like this:
reg enterprise(if followup="Folowup") i.aimag group loan_baseline eduvoc edusec age16 under16 marr_cohab age age_sq buddhist hahl sep_f nov_f enterprise(if followup ="Baseline"), vce(cluster soum)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`followup` is a numeric variable with value labels, as its colouring in the Data Editor makes clear, so you can't test its values directly for equality or inequality with literal strings. (And if you could, the match needs to be exact, as `Folowup` would not be read as implying `Followup`.)

There is a syntax for identifying observations by value labels: see [U] 13.11 in the pdf documentation or https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0009.

However, it is usually easiest just to use the numeric value underneath the value label. So if the variable `followup` had numeric values 0 and 1, you would test for equality with 0 or 1.

You must use `==` not `=` for testing for equality here:

```
 ... if followup == 1
```

For any future Stata questions, please see the Stata tag wiki for detailed advice on how to present data. Screenshots are usually difficult to read and impossible to copy, and leave many details about the data obscure.